# ASP.NET MVC Bundles not picking latest updated scripts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to use bundles for registering scripts in my project.

I notice that the runtime isn't picking updated scripts into the bundle collection.
Is there some settings to be made for the bundles so that  files are minified as changes are made to existing files ?

Comment: Make sure the changes you've done are replicated in .min files also

Comment: If you have a corresponding `.min.js` file, the bundler will use those, so just remove the `.min.js` files and let the bundler do the minifying